# Flutter Single Statefullwidget with multiple State

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wanna ask your opinion about this one…

when creating a statefull widget, we need to create a state for it. and this is tiresome when I need to have multiple widgets that changes….
I wanna create it more simpler way bu creating only one Statefullwidget, but with multiple State….
basically like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefullWidget {
    final State<MyWidget> state;
    MyWidget({this.state});
}

abstract MyStatefull extends State<MyWidget> {
}
```

Then every statefullwidget that I wanna create is extending this `MyStatefull` class….

Is this a good approach? and if there are some flaw in it, please kindly tell me…. 
Thanks…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work.

Using such code, you may find yourself losing the state of `MyState.state` after something updated in the widget tree (hot-reload, keyboard opens, ...)

Not only that, but the property `context` of your custom `State` will never be set and you'll be missing out on some health checks from Flutter.

It *is* doable to some extent, but not using `State`. You can use a custom class that mimic the behavior of `State`, and have an *actual* `State` class delegate its implementation to your custom class.

The package [provider](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider) does that internally, under the name `DelegateWidget` and `StateDelegate`.

The implementation is available [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/packages/provider/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart)

Comment: I overlook this one... so this delegate will be responsible on creating  and destroying the widget right? no wonder that I find my approach is cannot useable with the device configuration changes...
thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score -1):

If the main purpose is to abbreviate the syntax I don't think it is the right approach. You can take a look at the snippets to autogenerate stateful widgets with VSCode or with Android Studio (`stful` in VSCode). Other thing you can take a look at is Flutter Hooks (based on React Hooks), which can abbreviate a lot the code when dealing with stateful widgets.

Comment: not because of the abbreviation.... I just don't wanna create too many class with almost same code on it, like what in the statefull widget classes which having the same method.. the only different is the state returned in the createState method...

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically it might be fine, but it might be worth checking how to use a mixin rather than inheritance.